# Anyone going to Black Hat ® Technical Security Conference: Abu Dhabi 2011??

Tags: discussion, conference

I am new in the field, and I don't know how popular Security Conferences are with you guys. I figured if at least 3 people say they are going, it would be worth me taking a Black Hawk flight to hop onto a C-130 or C-17 from Afghanistan to get to this Black Hat ® Technical Security Conference: Abu Dhabi 2011 thing.

So is anyone going?

http://www.blackhat.com/html/bh-ad-11/bh-ad-11-home.html

Comment: @Abdu - Welcome to the site.  IT Security StackExchange is a Q&A site intended to address objectively answerable questions based on real-world problems.  It is not meant to be an open-discussion forum.  However, we do have a Meta site (http://meta.stackexchange.com/) that may be more accepting of "discussion" topics which are not quite on-target for the regular Q&A section.  Please read our FAQ:  http://security.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Hi @Abdu, you could also try grabbing folks over at the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151)

Comment: Black Hat is a well-respected conference - thanks for putting this out.  I'd be happy to jump on the bus.  Where is the nearest C-17 stop to Boulder CO?  :)

Comment: @Nealmcb - nearly made me spill my wooded chardonnay. :-)

Comment: @nealmcd Request the Blackhawk....its comes to your doorstep

Comment: I'd be too concerned about my (personal) physical security to pay attention to any technical security presentation.  Overload

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how many folks on here are from the emirates so don't be too disappointed if no-one answers...

Comment: I am not from the Emirates neither - but I know that conference isn't for the locals is you know what I mean. It is a tourist/business town. THIS does, however, answer my question on assessing its populaity :-) I just don't know if I should assume this to be for the entire IT Security industy - or just for the Middle-Eastern IT Security. I mean, do IT Security people rather stay home, or do they get out and mingle at such events.

Comment: Oh there is an awful lot of mingling at the major events, however the big BlackHat cons are Vegas and Washington. The Europe one is quite a bit smaller.

Comment: Vegas is pretty much *THE* conference.  There are an awful lot of people there, and two other conferences occur following/during.  If you can get the time, i'd highly recommend it.  I know folks who come in from AF specifically for this, bumpy C-130 ride and all.  It's well worth the trip.